# Which timer class to use for a metronome?

Tags: c#, timer

The .net framework has many ways to use timers, but for a metronome which one should I use ?

I tried all these timers but no one is enough accurate for my use (they can't have a resolution under 15ms).

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer
System.Web.UI.Timer
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch   
System.Timers.Timer
System.Threading.Timer
```

For my metronome class I need `Ticks` reliable , constant, without drift.

I found this implementation on MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692(v=vs.85).aspx that use "coredll.dll"

Another solution can be to implement these native methods:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "timeSetEvent")]
internal static extern UInt32 TimeSetEvent(UInt32 msDelay, UInt32 msResolution, MultimediaTimerCallback callback, ref UInt32 userCtx, UInt32 eventType);

[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "timeKillEvent")]
internal static extern void TimeKillEvent(UInt32 uTimerId);
```

What is the best way to have a timer with a resolution under 5ms on windows ?

**EDIT**

I found this very interesting link about timers in .net (in french) : 
http://www.e-naxos.com/Blog/post/NET-et-ses-timers-Prise-de-tete-ou-reelle-utilite-.aspx

Comment: Have you tried the DispatcherTimer ?

Comment: The `DispatcherTimer` has the same resolution as others, the best one is `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. `DispatcherTimer` is indicated to manipulate objects UI and it is not accurate because evaluated on the Dispatcher stack or am I wrong ?

Comment: seems legit. I just very ofthen use this one since it seems to be the one with the most fuctions which fit me needs.

Comment: timeSetEvent() is pretty much designed for this, you'll however also have to call timeBeginPeriod() to make the resolution good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [Multimedia Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this purpose.

> Multimedia timer services allow applications to schedule timer events
>   with the greatest resolution (or accuracy) possible for the hardware
>   platform. These multimedia timer services allow you to schedule timer
>   events at a higher resolution than other timer services.
>
> These timer services are useful for applications that demand
>   high-resolution timing. For example, a MIDI sequencer requires a
>   high-resolution timer because it must maintain the pace of MIDI events
>   within a resolution of 1 millisecond.

There are various C# libraries available to help use these.

For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

As @Guillaume noted in the comments, seems `StopWatch` works as a managed replacement for performance counters. So I guess you should use that

---

If you want precision, I'd definitely use the native `QueryPerformanceCounter`, however the one you linked is for .NET Compact Framework (`coredll`)... for Windows, you need to use `kernel32`.

I have a **very old** (2003) timer implementation of `QueryPerformanceCounter` on C# [on this link](http://files.javiercampos.info/code/timer.cs). It has dependency on other modules but should be easy to remove (I think the only dependency is for logging the exception on the `Initialize()` method, but I haven't touched that code in 13 years... it was C# 1.0 running on .NET 1.0).

Note that this won't issue events, you'll need to handle your own loop and check for the elapsed time.

That said, under 5ms is a very very low precision and you shouldn't rely on anything (as long as your computer is doing other things, even garbage collecting your own application) that work on a 5 millisecond precision. If your metronome application emits a sound, unless it's Windows 10, you probably already have more than 5ms latency (Windows 10 low-latency standard sound driver stack has 4.5ms for integer data and 16ms for floating point data).

Comment: from `StopWatch` documentation : "the Frequency field and GetTimestamp method can be used in place of the unmanaged Win32 APIs QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: @Guillaume yeah, it seems that wasn't available when I wrote that timer... I don't use any hi-res timing these days (I do use Stopwatch to measure functions though)... so definitely, it should be a replacement. I'll update with that remark

Comment: Thx for your help very interesting post.

Comment: Using Stopwatch is a bad idea, you can only observe an interval by constantly polling it.  Burning 100% core.  That gives the OS a very good reason to put the thread into the dog house for a while after it has burned through its quantum.  Incurs a delay of 45 msec or more.  Not obvious in a casual test program, happens when the machine is busy.

Comment: @HansPassant i have used performance counters in the past by polling on a non-blocking loop (using Thread.Sleep on the polling thread). Probably not the best method (this was ages ago and have never needed it afterwards), but yes, I get your point

Comment: When you call Thread.Sleep() then you're back to the original problem, it won't sleep for 5 msec but longer.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree... since I mentioned in my answer, 5ms is just too low latency for doing almost anything. Even if your process is very quick, in a managed environment, unless you fine-grain its control, the garbage collector can kick in, other processes in the OS can fill up the CPU, and whatnot. I guess you can do <1ms accurate event-timers using winmm.dll (if that's a thing in modern windows still), but there are plenty of non-trivial situations where you will more likely find your events are not being called every exactly 1ms. <5ms precision for a metronome app is just overkill.